# Modify child property of json object in logic app

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

Below is my json object and i want to change "First Name" from "Tom" to anything (let suppose "David"). How can i do this in logic app.Any expression for this

```
{
"Book" : {
    "Author" : {
        "Name" : {
            "First Name" : "Tom",
            "Last Name" : "Brown"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joey for your answer .Actually it worked me by using this expression- setProperty(triggerBody(),'Author',setProperty(variables('AuthorObject'),'Name',setProperty(variables('NameObject'), 'FirstName', 'TheBeast')))                         .But i will try your approach too and if it worked then will mark as answer

Comment: I have update it into my reply, both of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `replace(string(variables('aaa')), 'Tom', 'joey')` to change "First Name" from "Tom" to "joey".

1.Firstly, use Initialize variable to include your data.

2.Secondly, use `replace(string(variables('aaa')), 'Tom', 'joey')` to change "First Name".

3.Finally, convert string to json.

[image]

The output is as below:

[image]

**Update**:

You can also use expression `setProperty` to achieve it as below:

```
setProperty(triggerBody(),'Author',setProperty(variables('AuthorObject'),'Name',setProperty(variables('NameObject'), 'FirstName', 'TheBeast')))
```